# Как с помощью cmake собрать проект под windows?

Tags: windows, cmake

Пишу, в основном, на линуксе, но, также интересуюсь сборкой своих прог под виндой. Для этого использовал `mingw` и `msys`- собирал с помощью линуксовой `make`. Но (так как `cmake` - кросплатформенная) хочу узнать как осуществить сборку без `mingw` и других портов с линукса (в проекте только стандартная библиотека)? Что для этого нужно, кроме самой `cmake`?

Comment: Что значит минуя `mingw`? Вы хотите собрать проект без использования компилятора?

Comment: @zed `mingw` - не родной (порт с линукса) компилятор. Я точно не в курсе, но разве на виндоус нету компилятора, который можно поставить без установки `mingw`?

Comment: Может я неверно выразился: `mingw` у меня установлен вместе с кучей сторонних библиотек и линуксовых прог. Я хотел узнать можно ли скомпилировать прогу не используя их (тот же `make` и `mingw`), а используя "родные" проги или как-то так.

Comment: Есть [Microsoft Visual Studio](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio). Неужели вы о ней не слышали? А MinGW - это в том числе и компилятор (порт gcc) + необходимый минимум для сборки. Так же, как и Visual Studio - это IDE + компилятор + toolchain.

Comment: Меня не интересует `IDE` под виндой. Меня вообще `IDE` не интересует: я пишу в `vim`, а для сборки использую `cmake` (ну и компилятор естественно). Вот и есть у меня, соответственно `git` с кодом и файлом `cmake`. В линукс просто скачал, ввел: `cmake`, `make` - готово. Что мне нужно сделать (если это возможно), чтобы сделать что-то подобное под виндой?

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, самый простой вариант окружения под Windows для компиляции кода на C/C++ без установки огромного Visual Studio - это как раз mingw.

Comment: @insolor, это не так. Есть [MSVC Build Tools](http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools)

Comment: @ixSci Даже эти tools занимают несколько Гб (2-4) в установленном виде, если ничего не путаю. А MinGW-w64 всего 0,5 Гб.

Answer (score 1):

Вам надо установить [Microsoft Visual Studio](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio) нужной версии, затем при помощи CMake сгенерировать проект для этой версии студии, а затем скомпилировать проект.

CMake поддерживает следующие генераторы проектов для студии:

```
The following generators are available on this platform:
  Visual Studio 15 2017 [arch] = Generates Visual Studio 2017 project files.
                                 Optional [arch] can be "Win64" or "ARM".
  Visual Studio 14 2015 [arch] = Generates Visual Studio 2015 project files.
                                 Optional [arch] can be "Win64" or "ARM".
  Visual Studio 12 2013 [arch] = Generates Visual Studio 2013 project files.
                                 Optional [arch] can be "Win64" or "ARM".
  Visual Studio 11 2012 [arch] = Generates Visual Studio 2012 project files.
                                 Optional [arch] can be "Win64" or "ARM".
  Visual Studio 10 2010 [arch] = Generates Visual Studio 2010 project files.
                                 Optional [arch] can be "Win64" or "IA64".
  Visual Studio 9 2008 [arch]  = Generates Visual Studio 2008 project files.
                                 Optional [arch] can be "Win64" or "IA64".
  Visual Studio 8 2005 [arch]  = Generates Visual Studio 2005 project files.
                                 Optional [arch] can be "Win64".
  Visual Studio 7 .NET 2003    = Deprecated.  Generates Visual Studio .NET
                                 2003 project files.
```

В качестве примера, последовательность действий для компиляции zlib в Visual Studio 2008:

```
    cmake . '-GVisual Studio 9 2008' \
        "-DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=1" \
        "-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release" \
        "-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=${BUILD_DIR}"

    msbuild.exe zlib.sln /verbosity:detailed /p:Configuration="Release"
    msbuild.exe install.vcproj /verbosity:detailed /p:Configuration="Release"
```

---

Опционально, можно не ставить полновесную IDE, а поставить только необходимый toolchain: [Visual C++ 2015 Build Tools](http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools). Но такая возможность есть не для всех версий студии.

Comment: неужели без IDE никак?

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch Дополнил ответ.